# Diference between preg_replace '/[^0-9]/' or '/\D/' or '/\d/'?

Tags: php, preg-replace

What's the difference between regular expressions **'/[^0-9]/'** or **'/\D/'** or **'/\d/'**? And is it better to use single o double quotes?

```
$number = '123asd456.789,123a4!"·$%&/()=/*-+<br>';

preg_replace('/\D/', '', $number) = 1234567891234
preg_replace('/\d/', '', $number) = asd.,a!"·$%&/()=/*-+
preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $number) = 1234567891234
```

Of course I did some testing and those were my results, I just want to undestand a bit more each regular expression. And which is better performance wise?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please replace "Thanks!!" with prior research to explain why you're confused about those particual placeholders. It's somewhat impolite to expect a lengthy explanation for one-liner questions.

Comment: `[0-9] \d [digit]` are all the same

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`\D`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_digit_non.asp) means anything, except number. It's alias of `[^0-9]`.
[`\d`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_digit.asp) means any number. It's alias of `[0-9]` (without `^`).
And there is no difference between `"` and `'`, because you are not using inner `"` or `'` and there is no PHP-variables-like inside this string.

Comment: Not really, `\d` is same as `\p{Digit}`, it matches more than `[0-9]`, it includes unicode digits and depends on locale. See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html

Comment: The long answer is "it depends" While PCRE stands for "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions", Perl and Python 3.x regexes permit other Unicode "digits" with \d while Python 2.x does not and PCRE does not _unless_ compiled with PCRE_UCP. Ultimately this means that if you really mean "just 0-9", use [0-9].

Comment: Slightly more direct link to info: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Digits

Answer (score 3):

```
\d identical with [0-9] - digits in expression
\D identical with [^0-9] - NOT digits in expression
```

I use single quotes.

In your example:

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $number) - 1234567891234
```

will replace all NON digits with ''

```
preg_replace('/\d/', '', $number) = asd.,a!"·$%&/()=/*-+
```

will replace all digits with ''

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $number) = 1234567891234
```

will replace all NON digits with ''

Comment: Not really, `\d` is same as `\p{Digit}`, it matches more than `[0-9]`, it includes unicode digits and depends on locale. See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html